# How to simulate Windows-D keypress in .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command, batch-processing

I want to write a Windows 7 batch file that will simulate pressing the "Windows Key" + D.

I know that this line of code will close all the open windows :

```
 powershell -command "& { $x = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application; $x.minimizeall() }"
```

... but sometimes one of the windows has a modal popup and doesn't close.  For example, Putty might be open with a modal message like "the connection to host was lost".

I want to run this batch file, and see the desktop - no matter what.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Is your question about a batch file, or about a PowerShell script? They are not the same thing. The tags say one thing, the code you've posted say differently. Which specifically are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

As it's unclear from your question whether you are asking about batch files or PowerShell (the tags say one, the question text refers to the other), I've answered related to PowerShell.

You can use `Shell.Application`, as you have, but call  [ToggleDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

```
powershell -command "& { $x = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application; $x.ToggleDesktop() }"
```

From the linked documentation:

> This method has the same effect as the **Show Desktop** button on the taskbar. It either hides all open windows to show the desktop or it hides the desktop by showing all open windows. The ToggleDesktop method does not display a user interface, it just invokes the toggle action.